# Load XML file into application output file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, clickonce

I have a folder in my main project that is separate than the Resources folder but also has some resources it that I would like to copy to the output folder as I reference it throughout the app.

I have set the build action to Resource, content, embedded content.. tried them all..

Also set it to always copy to output directory.

Now, from within my application I'm entering

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Dashboard\\Role.xml";
```

or also

```
"..\\..\\Dashboard\\Role.xml";
```

for the path and get an exception that says that the file can not be found.

Both of these paths work in my development machine but not once I deploy through click once.

I have tried to add it to the application files in the publish section as suggested in another post but it does not appear there.

I have also tried to put it in the resources folder and still nothing.... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I followed some steps in this link and got it working:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx

Basically, you mark the file as build action "Content" and set it to always copy.

Then, you go to the application files in the publish section of your clickonce application and they will now show up.

Switch them from datafile to "Include" and you're set!